# How to write a c++ template that works for both a map and vector of pair>

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-templates

I'd like to write a template function that iterates over a container of `std::pair` and returns a templated value with both types in the pair. I've gotten this to work for `std::map` as follows:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::pair<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>> unzip(const std::map<T1,T2>& zipped)
{
    auto unzipped = std::make_pair(std::vector<T1>(), std::vector<T2>());
    for (auto& one_two : zipped)
    {
        unzipped.first.push_back(one_two.first);
        unzipped.second.push_back(one_two.second);
    }
    return unzipped;
}
```

This works fine, but it restricts the container to be `std::map`. What I'd like to accomplish is to have this also work for something like `std::vector<std::pair<T1,T2>>`, since the iteration over both containers works the same way.

I've tried to make the container a template by changing the template arguments:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, template<typename ... Types> class Container>
std::pair<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>> unzip(const Container<T1,T2>& zipped)
{
//do stuff and return
}
```

but in this case, the deduction fails if not using `std::map` because `std::vector` depends on only a single type. Then I tried getting more creative, but the compiler just complained even more:

```
template <typename PairContainerType>
std::pair<std::vector<typename PairContainerType::value_type::first_type>,
          std::vector<typename PairContainerType::value_type::second_type>>
unzip(const PairContainerType& zipped)
{
typedef typename PairContainerType::value_type::first_type T1;
typedef typename PairContainerType::value_type::second_type T2;
//do the same stuff and return
}
```

I think what I'm trying to do should be possible, but I'm at a loss. I'm using `c++11` if that matters, though if what I want is available in future versions I'm still interested in those solutions. Thank you.

---

Update:
Thanks to RiaD I got the following to work using c++11:

```
template <typename PairContainerType,
          typename T1 = typename std::remove_const<typename PairContainerType::value_type::first_type>::type,
          typename T2 = typename std::remove_const<typename PairContainerType::value_type::second_type>::type>
std::pair<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>> unzip(const PairContainerType& zipped)
{
//do stuff and return
}
```

Note that it's slightly different than the accepted answer, since it uses `std::remove_const` instead of `std::remove_const_t` and needs to have `::type` added at the end.

RiaD also points out that the template types `T1` and `T2` can be overridden by whoever is making the call. As suggested by Jarod42, this can be mitigated with some extra typing, which leaves me in the final c++11 solution:

```
template <typename PairContainerType>
std::pair<std::vector<typename std::remove_const<typename PairContainerType::value_type::first_type>::type>, 
          std::vector<typename std::remove_const<typename PairContainerType::value_type::second_type>::type>>
unzip(const PairContainerType& zipped)
{
    auto unzipped = std::make_pair(
        std::vector<typename std::remove_const<typename PairContainerType::value_type::first_type>::type>(), 
        std::vector<typename std::remove_const<typename PairContainerType::value_type::second_type>::type>());

    for (const auto& one_two : zipped)
    {
        unzipped.first.push_back(one_two.first);
        unzipped.second.push_back(one_two.second);
    }
    return unzipped;
}
```

Overall, c++14 and c++17 are looking pretty appealing. I could have saved myself time with the `auto` return feature!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually with c++ you just allow any type and let it fail if it's not correct one. To get T1 and T2 you may get value_type of collection (exists in both `std::map` and `std::vector<std::pair<>>` and others e.g `std::set<std::pair<>>`)

```
template <typename T, typename T1 = std::remove_const_t<typename T::value_type::first_type>, typename T2 = std::remove_const_t<typename T ::value_type::second_type>>
std::pair<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>> unzip(const T& zipped)
{
    auto unzipped = std::make_pair(std::vector<T1>(), std::vector<T2>());
    for (auto& one_two : zipped)
    {
        unzipped.first.push_back(one_two.first);
        unzipped.second.push_back(one_two.second);
    }
    return unzipped;
}
```

It has (slight) downside that somebody may force T1 and T2 as they fit. You may remove them from list of template args.

```
template <typename T>
auto /* or return type (but it will require copy-pasting) before c++14*/ 
unzip(const T& zipped)
{
    using T1 = std::remove_const_t<typename T::value_type::first_type>; //may need to remove const
    using T2 = std::remove_const_t<typename T::value_type::second_type>; 
    // impl
}
```

Removing const is needed because value_type of `std::map` is `std::pair<const K, V>`. it may be done without `std::remove_const_t` if you need older standard support e.g. for c++11 you need `typename std::remove_const<>::type`

Comment: This doesn't compile for me because the deduced type for T1 and T2 are const

Comment: *"You may remove them from list of template args (but that will require `auto` return type from c++11 or c++14)"*. `auto` is not required, it is just more convenient (as least the C++14 one).

Comment: @Jarod42 c++14 is not needed, yes (that's why I write c++11 *or* c++14 and left comment where to write return type for c++11). But I don't know way to do that in c++98 (there might be one, but compatibility with c++98 is usually not an issue for me so I never *really* thought of way to fix this under c++98)

Comment: By using verbose `std::pair<std::vector<typename remove_const<typename T::value_type::first_type>::type>, std::vector<typename remove_const<typename T::value_type::second_type>::type>>` (by also rewriting `remove_const`) twice (in return type, and in body).

Comment: @Jarod42 ah, of course, for some reason I thought I can't use T in return type, updated

Comment: This is what I want to use, but these templates are driving me insane. I've never used ```std::remove_const``` (after including ```<type_traits>``` I don't seem to have ```std::remove_const_t```). When using the c++11 solution, the compiler can't seem to convert the return values from the ```remove_const``` back to ```const```:
```no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<std::remove_const<const MyClass>, std::allocator<std::remove_const<const MyClass> > >’ to ‘const VecType& 
{aka const std::vector<MyClass>&}’```

Comment: std::remove_const_t is c++14, right, so you need to use `typename std::remove_const<T::value_type>::type`. `std::remove_const` is (unrelated) type itself

Comment: @RiaD thank you! That ```::type``` was the last hint I needed. It works now. That c++14 auto return type is nice though, I hope my team migrates ahead soon.

Answer (score -1):

```
template<class T>
    struct zipper {
    using first_t = remove_cv_t<typename T::value_type::first_type>;
    using second_t = typename T::value_type::second_type;

    template <class container>
    static std::pair<std::vector<first_t>, std::vector<second_t>> unzip(const container& zipped)
    {
        auto unzipped = std::make_pair(std::vector<first_t>(), std::vector<second_t>());
        for (auto& one_two : zipped)
        {
            unzipped.first.emplace_back(one_two.first);
            unzipped.second.emplace_back(one_two.second);
        }
        return unzipped;
    }
};


template<class container>
auto unzip(const container& cont)  {
    return zipper<container>::unzip(cont);
}
```

Comment: std::map doesn't get std::pair as one template argument

Comment: you asked for a method that accepts an `std::container of type std::pair<T,U>` the code I posted works for an `std::vector<std::pair<T,U>>`

Comment: are you asking for a single method that can handle both cases?

Comment: it's not me who asking. (and I think yes, single method is what is asked (but I can be wrong, ofc)